# How do I load an mpeg-dash video in Google Chrome

Tags: html, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I need to load a mpeg-dash video in Google Chrome. Is it possible to load an mpeg-dash video format directly into the HTML5 video tag? Do I need an external library? If I can load it directly to a video tag. What value do I set for the type attribute on the source tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome does only provide the decoding interface to decode and render DASH content. The interpretation, download of the media segments, bitrate adaptation, etc. has to be done in a JS player implementation.

Therefore you can use either the DASH-IF impelmentation dash.js http://dashif.org/software/ or the bitdash player on http://www.dash-player.com. Both are free.

Best, 
Stefan